# Laravel: How to get DoB?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

When given a form, say, a registration form and you require the guest to input their birthday in order to register, how do you get the data out of all three inputs and combine it into one BEFORE putting it in the database?

In Laravel, I have a form input like so:

```
<select name="birthdayMonth">
  <option value="1">January</option>
</select>
<select name="birthdayDay">
  <option value="1">01</option>
</select>
<select name="birthdayYear">
  <option value="1900">1900</option>
</select>
```

So, with this, when I click submit and the POST controller receives the call, this is what I have the method doing:

```
  public function processRegister() {
    $user = new User(Input::all());
    $user->password = md5(Input::get('password'));
    $user->save();

    return View::make('user.registerSuccess');
  }
```

Okay, so, how do I format those THREE inputs that are being passed in with Input::all() into ONE birthday input? I don't have "birthdayMonth", "birthdayDay", and "birthdayYear" tables in my database. All I have is a timestamp "birthday".

Do I need to make it look ugly in the model and guard against the mass assignment of those three inputs, or is there a prettier and seemingly better way to do this?

If you require more information, please let me and I will oblige as quickly as possible.

Thanks.

Comment: For reference: This is a test file. No, the md5() call is not going anywhere on the actual internet. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$user = new User(Input::all());
$user->password = md5(Input::get('password'));

$birthday = Input::get('birthdayYear')."-".Input::get('birthdayMonth')."-".Input::get('birthdayDay');

$user->birthday = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($birthday));
$user->save();
```

Try something like this :)

Comment: Hey thanks, but what I'm saying is that the fields birthdayYear, birthdayMonth, and birthdayDay are all sent into the database already with Input::all() and Laravel errors out. Do I need to "guard" those fields? I'd prefer not to, but if I have to then I will.

Comment: do you want to validate those fields ?

Comment: No, I just want to throw them away and make sure they're not even shown to the model. I want to turn them into 1 value and then pass it into the model. I'm guessing the way to do this is to guard them so the model ignores them when passing in Input::all(), yes?

Comment: You can use `Input::except('birthdayYear','birthdayMonth','birthdayDay');` instead of `Input::all()`, this way, these inputs won't be inserted in your model.

Comment: @jdersen sorry bro didnt get your comment. could u please tell the exactly what u want.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to convert your date to a timestamp, using the day, month and year data. See the PHP function [mktime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php)();

```
$input = Input::all();
$input->birthday = mktime(0,0,0, $input['month'], $input['day'], $input['year']); 
$user = new User($input);
$user->save();
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks. I posted a reply to Kalhano's answer. That reply has to do with your answer as well, so please see that :)

Comment: Okay. Try this:
`$input = Input::all();$input->birthday = mktime(0,0,0, $input['month'], $input['day'], $input['year']); $user = new User($input);`

Comment: Hmm, close, but not quite. MrShibby has it, though. Thanks again for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

**Laravel user**
**Date of Birth dob**
======add this in your blade/ user.blade.php=======

```
<input id="dob" type="date" class="form-control" name="dob" value="{{ old('dob') }}" required autofocus>
   @if ($errors->has('dob'))
   <span class="help-block">
   <strong>{{ $errors->first('dob') }}</strong>
   </span>
    @endif
```

=========Then Model/ user.php ======

```
protected $dates = [
    'dob'
    ];
```

====== Controller / UserController.php=====

```
'dob' => $data['dob'],
```

***hope it hepls***